# Subdimensional array from multidimensional array in Julia

Tags: julia, array-indexing

With NumPy I can access a [subdimensional array from a multidimensional array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing) without knowing the dimension of the original array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))  # A 2-by-3-by-4 array of zeros
a[0]  # A 3-by-4 array of zeros
```

but with Julia I am at a loss. It seems that I must know the dimension of `a` to do this:

```
a = zeros(2, 3, 4)  # A 2-by-3-by-4 array of zeros
a[1, :, :]  # A 3-by-4 array of zeros
```

What should I do if I **don't** know the dimension of `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectdim` gives a view of what you are looking for,

```
a = zeros(2, 3, 4)
selectdim(a,1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over each "subdimensional array" in order, you can also use `eachslice`:

```
julia> a = reshape(1:24, (2, 3, 4));

julia> eachslice(a, dims = 1) |> first
3×4 view(reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 2, 3, 4), 1, :, :) with eltype Int64:
 1   7  13  19
 3   9  15  21
 5  11  17  23

julia> for a2dims in eachslice(a, dims = 1)
         @show size(a2dims)
       end
size(a2dims) = (3, 4)
size(a2dims) = (3, 4)
```